# Roman numerals for table of contents, arabic for main text in footer

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, page-numbering

I am trying to use roman numerals for the table of contents (and abstract, notes of thanks etc.) and then start the main body of the text from page 1 in arabic numerals. I am using the article document class and do not want a page number on the title page.
At the same time in the footer I want to show Page x of y.

i.e. I want

Title page: no number
Table of contents first page: Page i of ii
Table of contents second page: page ii of ii [ii was just chosen for this example]
First page of document: page  1 of x
Second page of document: page 2 of x

The code works fine for the table of contents, i do get page i of ii, page ii of ii etc.  However, for the rest of the document I then get page 1 of ii, page 2 of ii Actually I can see what causes the mistake (the use of a `\label{lastromanpage}`), but I do not know how to solve this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\Title}{Title}
\newcommand{\DueDate}{\today}
\newcommand{\Class}{}
\newcommand{\ClassTime}{}
\newcommand{\ClassInstructor}{}
\newcommand{\AuthorName}{Authorname}

\title{\vspace{2in}\textmd{\textbf{ \Title}}\\\normalsize\vspace{0.1in}\small{Due\ on\ \DueDate}\\\vspace{0.1in}\large{\textit{\ClassInstructor\ \ClassTime}}\vspace{3in}}
\date{}
\author{\textbf{\AuthorName}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\AuthorName}
\chead{\Class}
\rhead{\Title}

\lfoot{\lastxmark}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{Page\ \thepage\ of\ \pageref{lastromanpage}}

\begin{document}\begin{spacing}{1.1}

\maketitle\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}\tableofcontents \label{lastromanpage}
\newpage\pagenumbering{arabic}\clearpage
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Issue `\rfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}` after `\pagenumbering{arabic}` and load the `lastpage` package (or `\zpageref{LastPage}` loading `zref-lastpage`).

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the footer inside the document with `\rfoot`. The label for the last page number is more complicate, because `\label` *after* the last page would not write anything in the `.aux` file. For example, package `lastpage` provides a label `LastPage` that can be used with `\pageref`.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\newcommand*{\Title}{Title}
\newcommand*{\AuthorName}{John Doe}
\title{\Title}
\date{}
\author{\AuthorName}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\AuthorName}
\chead{Class}
\rhead{\Title}

\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{Page\ \thepage\ of\ \pageref{lastromanpage}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\label{lastromanpage}
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\rfoot{Page\ \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\section{First section}
\newpage
\section{Last section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this seems to work just fine ^^